# FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult valueForUndefinedKey when trying to get user's email

Tags: swift, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to get user's name , email and id from FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult and get an error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
>   reason: '[
>   valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant
>   for the key email.'

Here's the code :

```
   class ViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {

        @IBOutlet weak var fbLogin: FBSDKLoginButton!
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
       fbLogin.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email"]
            fbLogin.delegate = self
    }

        func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {


            if ((error) != nil)
            {
                NSLog("User Logged In")
            }
            else if result.isCancelled {
                 NSLog("User cancels")
            }
            else {
                if result.grantedPermissions.contains("email")
                {             
                   let userEmail : String = result.valueForKey("email") as! String //here I get crash
                    NSLog("User Email is: \(userEmail)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Also, I can't find list of available keys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you need to make a FBSDKGraphRequest. I have

```
func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {

    if ((error) != nil) {
        // Process error
    } else if result.isCancelled {
        // Handle cancellations
    } else {
        let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields" : "id, email, name"])
        graphRequest.start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
            if ((error) != nil) {
                print("Error: \(error)")
            } else {
                if let user : NSString = result!.value(forKey: "name") as? NSString {
                    //print("user2: \(user)")
                    self.userLabel.text = "Logged in as \(user)"
                }
                if let id : NSString = result!.value(forKey: "id") as? NSString {
                    self.fbId = id
                    //print("id: \(id)")
                }
                if let email : NSString = result!.value(forKey: "email") as? NSString {
                    print("email: \(email)")
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

This example is using swift ver. 3 (xcode beta 3).

Comment: Good! except for : valueForKey( instead of value(forKey: and graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler instead of graphRequest.start(

Comment: Pardon, this is swift ver. 3. I'll add this to my answer.

Comment: That's what I hate about swift : they don't make deprecated methods, they force you to rewrite the whole project :)

Comment: True. I started the project with swift ver. 2. After I installed xcode beta errors surfaced . Since I had just begun I let xcode-beta upgrade the project to ver. 3. and had these changes. Hope they stabilize the syntax soon. :-)

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 4:

```
func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {
        if ((error) != nil) {
           // ERROR
        }
        else if result.isCancelled {
            // CANCELATION
        }
        else {
            let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields" : "id, email, name"])
            graphRequest.start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                if ((error) != nil) {
                    FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()
                } else {
                    if let idfb : NSString = (result! as AnyObject).value(forKey: "id") as? NSString {
                        print("ID FROM FACEBOOK: \(idfb)")
                    }
                    if let name : NSString = (result! as AnyObject).value(forKey: "name") as? NSString {
                        print("NAME IN FACEBOOK: \(name)")
                    }
                    if let email : NSString = (result! as AnyObject).value(forKey: "email") as? NSString {
                        print("EMAIL IN FACEBOOK: \(email)")
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
```